# How do I query between 2 tables with no foreign key link

Tags: sql, sqlplus

[image]

I've attached the physical model. I'm trying to get all flights from a destination from the flight table that is associated with the service_point table that has all the location code with the associated name.

Table 1

[image]

Table 2

[image]

Comment: Please post as text rather than images for tables

Comment: Tables don't need to have foreign keys defined to be joined. You can join on anything: `... from A join B on <any boolean expression>`

Comment: 1) Please post text, not images.  2) Use your "origin" and "destination" columns to link ("join") the tables

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
select * from flight where 
ORI IN(select LOC from service_point) OR
DES IN (select LOC from service_point)
```

or

```
select * from flight a,  service_point b
where a.ORI = b.LOC 
OR a.DES = b.LOC
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see that location_code from service_point table can be joined with origin from the flight table.
You can define your query like this.

```
   select f.flight_no 
    from service_point sp join flight f
       on (sp.location_code = f.origin)
    where f.destination = ?1
```